# Grouping dates in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

im trying to group my objects by year only year in datetime field.

```
{% regroup notificacoes by criados|date:"Y" as criados_list %}
      <ul>
        {% for x in criados_list %}
          <li>
            {{ x.grouper }}
            <ul>
              {% for y in x.list %}
                <li>{{ y.slug }} : {{ y.arquivo }}</li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```

this was supposed to work, but is not working

Comment: What datetime field ? criados is key of notificacoes ?

Comment: criados is a DateTimeField in a model norificacoes